# How to password protect Power BI report sent as PDF attachment

Tags: powerbi

Following links talks about Power BI dashboard / report subscritpion on email:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe

As per the link, it says Power BI dashboard / report can be sent as an attachemnt in PDF format.

But how we can provide a password protection to this PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Bi is not able to generate password protection on the pdf you sent from the Power Bi web automatically. One of the solution is to print out your file in pdf, and manually protect it with password.

**Reference:**

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/set-a-password-on-the-generated-pdf-file-with-report-builder/m-p/1060823